# Call Wcf service with Javascript in Html page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, wcf

I have a WCF project in VSStudio2012 and I want to call a method from JavaScript function.

JavaScript file :

```
var url = 'http://localhost:52768/Service1.svc/'

function test() {

var response;

$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: url + 'GetTEST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },

    error: function (e) {
        alert("Error  : " + e.statusText);
    }
});
```

}

HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/JavaScript1.js"></script>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.intellisense.js"></script>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<title>TESTE</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="test()"/>
</body>

</html>
```

In my IService1.cs

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetTEST();
```

Here is that alert display

[image]

And the error :

[image]

localhost:52768/Service1.svc display

[image]

Comment: __sidenote__: Why are you loading multiple versions of jQuery?

Comment: What's `GetTEST()` implementation?

Comment: @chridam public string GetTEST()
        {
            return "OKKKKKKKK";
        }

Comment: @Satpal sorry, i had tested several things, I forget to remove

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/11ddeceb-ca55-4d17-8c79-dd18104456a9/ajax-call-to-wcf-returns-400-bad-request), the issue is that AJAX has [cross-site limitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) which prevents you to call remote service. For such cases, a simple workaround is define a server-side page_method (script callback) or local wcf service within the same application which use server-side code to call the remote WCF service. And your web page use AJAX to call the local WCF service (which works like an intermediary).

Another approach is defining your remote WCF service as a standard REST service which accept http GET request. Thus, your web page can use JQuery api to access the remote WCF service operation through JQuery script. You then host your WCF service as a console application and use JQuery in another web application to call it:

```
  [ServiceContract(Namespace="ConsoleAJAXWCF")]
  public interface IService1
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetTEST();
  }

  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class Service1 : IService1
  {

    public string GetTEST()
    {
      return "OKKKKKKKK";
    }
  }
```

You hosting console application:

```
// program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description; 
using ConsoleAJAXWCF;    

namespace ConsoleAJAXWCF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Step 1 Add a service endpoint.
            using (WebServiceHost selfHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1)))
            {
                try
                {
                   // Step 2 Start the service.
                   selfHost.Open();
                   Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
                   Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
                   Console.WriteLine();
                   Console.ReadLine();

                   // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
                   selfHost.Close();
                }
                catch (CommunicationException ce)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                    selfHost.Abort();
                }                
            }            
        }
    }
}
    // WCF Configuration    
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="AJAXEndpoint" >
       <webHttp/>
       </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleAJAXWCF.Service1">
        <endpoint 
         behaviorConfiguration="AJAXEndpoint" 
         address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleAJAXWCF.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:52768/Service1/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Verify the service is working:

1. Run the ConsoleAJAXWCF console application from inside Visual Studio 2012. When running on Windows Vista and later operating systems, the service must be run with administrator privileges. Because Visual Studio was run with Administrator privileges, GettingStartedHost is also run with Administrator privileges. You can also start a new command prompt running it with Administrator privileges and run service.exe within it.
2. Open Internet Explorer and browse to the service's debug page at localhost:52768/Service1/

Code in ASPX page which calls the service:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
      <script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.intellisense.js"></script>
      <script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
      <script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
      <script Language="JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
      <title>TESTE</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="CallRESTWCFService()"/>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function CallRESTWCFService() {
      $.getJSON("http://localhost:52768/Service1/GetTEST", {},
        function (data) {
          alert(data);
        });       
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand when you speak about hosting console application. Where should I place this code?

Comment: If you follow this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx) that should guide you

Comment: I follow the guide and I have this error : 
GET http://localhost:52768/Service1/GetTEST 404 (Not Found)

Comment: An other question, when I want to access to http://localhost:52768/Service1.svc/GetTEST, I have a blank page, is this normal?

Comment: You need to run the service first via the console app, I've updated my answer to include this guide. This should hopefully solve the issues you are facing.

Comment: Yes, I run the service via the console app. It displays "service started". And then, I right click on my HTML page (run with google chrome). I have 2 buttons, with $.ajax, I have a 400 Bad Request and with $.getJSON, I have 404 (Not Found)Error. When I want to access to localhost:52768/Service1.svc/GetTEST, I have a blank page, is this normal?

Comment: Ok it works, my error is that I closed the console and then I run the HTML page. I just wanted to know why it doesn't work with $. ajax?

Comment: I solved my problem with $. ajax by putting directly the full url. Thanks.

Comment: Oh nice, glad you found out the issue and how to fix it. Cheers!

Comment: The service in the question is already REST. Using a console app as a local client of the WCF service is simply a design choice and doesn't constitute a rework into a REST implementation.