# No ajax call on WCF service with method

Tags: c#, json, ajax, wcf, bad-request

I am sending a simple ajax call with WCF method, whenit is returning `bad-request` but without method it is showing status to success

**Ajax Call**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.get("http://localhost:1347/Service1.svc/DoWork", //this shows bad-request
          //$.get("http://localhost:1347/Service1.svc", //this shows success
function(data, status){

                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

**Operation Contract**

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string DoWork();
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public string DoWork()
        {
            return string.Format("This is DoWork()");
        }
    }
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

**Web.Config (Edit)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>


    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>




  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Making a request to `Service1.svc` is quite different from `Service1.svc/DoWork`, since the first one will return an information page about the service and the second one will execute a method.

Comment: how to execute second one?

Comment: Can you browse to http://localhost:1347/Service1.svc/DoWork with a browser, eg. Chrome?

Comment: attach the config here i think the issue is with config

Comment: showing empty screen in chrome with this error in console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: Have you created a webHttpBinding element to your web.config?

Comment: basicHttpBinding will be enough for this, creating binding is the most important part in configuring a WCF service. atach your configuration file here .

Comment: added config @AmarnathRShenoy and JoãoLourenço

Comment: @QadeerMangrio loking to this this might help to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970848/call-wcf-service-with-javascript-in-html-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you enable GET in your contract.

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "DoWork", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string DoWork();
    }
}
```

And then make sure to add `webHttp` in your config.

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

You also might need to set your binding to [`webHttpBindig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176(v=vs.110).aspx).

I usually define my endpoints, but I **think** you can manage without it. This should be a complete example.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="myWebBehavior" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myWebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

A complete example can be found here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: Yes, it was wrong. `webHttp` is an `endpointbehavior`. I've updated with a complete example.

Comment: following the example in link you have provided. I did exactly same, with this link in browser http://localhost:3700/TestService.svc/json/123 retuned this `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: With the solution provided you should be able to call http://localhost:1347/Service1.svc/DoWork. But not pass the parameters with trailing slashes.

Comment: however this helped me much, almost I can say accepted.