# How to use my C# webservice methods and call them to my website

Tags: c#, web-services, methods

I have a c# webservice with some methods that look like this:

```
[OperationContract]
    public List<CSMaquina> GetMaquinaByLoja(String IDLoja)
    {
        try
        {
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Maquina WHERE LJA_ID = @LJA_ID";
            List<CSParameter> Parameters = new List<CSParameter>();
            CSParameter parameter = new CSParameter();
            parameter.FieldName = "LJA_ID";
            parameter.FieldSize = 0;
            parameter.FieldType = (int)enFieldType.Integer;
            parameter.Value = IDLoja;
            Parameters.Add(parameter);

            DataTable dt = ExecuteQuery(queryString, Parameters, CommandType.Text);

            List<CSMaquina> Maquinas = new List<CSMaquina>();
            CSMaquina maquina;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                maquina = new CSMaquina();
                maquina.LJA_ID = int.Parse(row["LJA_ID"].ToString());
                maquina.MAQ_Numero = int.Parse(row["MAQ_Numero"].ToString());

                Maquinas.Add(maquina);
            }

            return Maquinas;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException(
                 new FaultReason(ex.Message),
                 new FaultCode("General"));
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if you can help me using that kind of methods to fill a comboBox in my site. I'm new in this webservices stuff so if you can say/teach to me the best way to integer that in my site I'll by very thankful.

Comment: Please provide some more details about the website, its platform, language, technologies being used, etc.

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko My website its a simple html doc (I have css, js files too obviously) with a simple structure and what I want its to fill my comboBoxes with the return values of my methods. What I really mean is if there is some kind of general way to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Check this answer first http://stackoverflow.com/a/21971394/920557